# Pdflatex on file with large amount of pictures

Tags: graphics, subfloats, minipage, memory, performance

I have a tex file that's generated by an automated bioinformatics pipeline as a report. Usually, this is roughly 50-150 pages, but that's based on 1-3 samples. It contains many quality control graphs. I now have a run with 60 samples, which explodes the size to 4026 pages. The problem is that `pdflatex` keeps failing when I include pictures. There are 8843 pictures in the file, in 4874 `figure` blocks  and they are all called within a `minipage` and `subfloat`, e.g. something like:

```
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Raw read 1]{
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{/data/DIV4/ihb-diabetes/projects/slik-tcell/analysis/01_gentrap_new/sample_H7-59-17-AN/lib_S61-L003/flexiprep/H7-59-17-AN_S61_L003_R1_001.fastqc/H7-59-17-AN_S61_L003_R1_001_fastqc/Images/sequence_length_distribution.png}
        }
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Preprocessed read 1]{
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{/data/DIV4/ihb-diabetes/projects/slik-tcell/analysis/01_gentrap_new/sample_H7-59-17-AN/lib_S61-L003/flexiprep/H7-59-17-AN_S61_L003_R1_001.qc.fastqc/H7-59-17-AN_S61_L003_R1_001.qc_fastqc/Images/sequence_length_distribution.png}
        }
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Read length distribution for read 1.}
    %\label{fig:length_dist_before_and_after_1}
\end{figure}
```

I keep getting these two errors:

```
!pdfTeX error: /usr/bin/pdflatex (file /data/DIV4/ihb-diabetes/projects/slik-tc
ell/analysis/01_gentrap_new/sample_B7-59-0-AM/lib_S46-L002/flexiprep/B7-59-0-AM
_S46_L002_R2_001.fastqc/B7-59-0-AM_S46_L002_R2_001_fastqc/Images/per_sequence_q
uality.png): buffer overflow at file ../../../texk/web2c/pdftexdir/utils.c, lin
e 183
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

and:

```
</data/DIV4/ihb-diabetes/projects/slik-tcell/analysis/01_gentrap_new/sample_B7-
59-0-AM/lib_S46-L002/flexiprep/B7-59-0-AM_S46_L002_R2_001.qc.fastqc/B7-59-0-AM_
S46_L002_R2_001.qc_fastqc/Images/per_sequence_gc_content.png, id=55775, 803.0pt
 x 602.25pt>
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pool size=6181497].
\Ginclude@png ...pty \else , page \GPT@page \fi >}
                                              \GPT@info {#1\ifx \GPT@pag...
l.144122             }

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

This happens even when I try to increase `pool_size` and `extra_mem_bot`. My final `pdflatex` call was:

```
'/usr/bin/pdflatex' -8bit --extra-mem-bot=11150000000 --pool-size=196181497  '-output-directory' '/data/DIV4/ihb-diabetes/projects/slik-tcell/analysis/01_gentrap_new/report'  '-jobname' 'gentrap_report'  '/data/DIV4/ihb-diabetes/projects/slik-tcell/analysis/01_gentrap_new/gentrap_report.tex'
```

The only way I managed to get a PDF file was by running pdflatex with another user which doesn't have permissions to read the folders where the pictures are located. Naturally, that resulted in a whole load of `permission denied` errors, but it got me something. That leads me to believe the errors are figure related. Would there be a way which reduces the memory load of my figures? (Whether a 4026 page report with nearly 9000 figures is a readable document is another question altogether).

Comment: What may help is to externalize your graphs (a feature of pgf).  This turns the figures into pdf files which are smaller in size but look exactly the same as if they were generated in a single run.

Comment: IIRC there is an upper limit to the memory pdfTeX can use without changing the source (something like 256M). You could try lualatex.

Comment: @MartinSchröder yes but pool size seems an odd limit to hit

Comment: what happens if you use more reasonable length filenames such as `sequence_length_distribution` instead of `/data/DIV4/ihb-diabetes/projects/slik-tcell/analysis/01_gentrap_new/sample_H7-59-17-AN/lib_S61-L003/flexiprep/H7-59-17-AN_S61_L003_R1_001.qc.fastqc/H7-59-17-AN_S61_L003_R1_001.qc_fastqc/Images/sequence_length_distribution.png` (You shouldn't need the full path, just make sure the images are in your TEXINPUTS path)

Comment: @JPi how would I do that?

Comment: See the TiKZ manual > Libraries > External.

Comment: @cfr tikz externalize can't help here can it? (since just including png files)

Comment: @JPi I don't see how you can externalize a png image?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Er... no, probably not. I was just responding to the question about how to externalise. Unless the pngs are created from tikz stuff, I don't see how it can help, though.

Comment: It wasn't the source of the problem, so it won't help.  But if it was the size of the png images that were the problem then something like this might help, no?\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfrealjobname{try2}

\begin{document}

\beginpgfgraphicnamed{tryme}
\includegraphics{try}
\endpgfgraphicnamed

\end{document}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the the length of the paths you are using.

```
\documentclass{article}
\batchmode
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcount\zz
\begin{document}
\def\z{}
\loop
\edef\z{\z/}
\includegraphics{/c/tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/..%
/tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/../tmp/\z house.png}\par
%\includegraphics{/c/tmp/\z house.png}\par
\advance\zz1
\ifnum\zz<1500
\repeat

\end{document}
```

Produces the error that you show, in my case

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pool size=6135010].
```

the `../tmp/......` construct just accesses the file `/c/tmp/house.png` but with
a suitably long path and the `\z` redefinition ensures that a distinct path is used every time.

Every distinct path uses up the string pool.

If you comment out the `\includegraphics` with the long path and use instead the one with a shorter path then the document succeeds with pool usage shown as

```
 5790653 string characters out of 6135010
```

In your case you could use

```
\includegraphics{sequence_length_distribution.png}
```

which would drastically reduce the string pool usage, you just need to ensure that the directory with the images is in the TEXINPUT path.

For example if they were in the current directory, or just set

```
TEXINPUTS=/data/DIV4/ihb-diabetes/projects/slik-tcell/analysis/01_gentrap_new/sample_B7-59-0-AM/lib_S46-L002/flexiprep/B7-59-0-AM_S46_L002_R2_001.fastqc/B7-59-0-AM_S46_L002_R2_001_fastqc/Images/:
```

before running latex.

Comment: Does `TEXINPUTS` work with relative paths? E.g., the common denominator of all images files is only `/data/DIV4/ihb-diabetes/projects/slik-tcell/`

Comment: @Gx1sptDTDa end the path segment with `//` and it will search all subdirectories from there. with that many files it would be worth having `!` at the front and using `texhash` to index the directory for `kpathsearch` like the main tex tree, but that just speeds it up, get it working first:-)